# Getting Jcharts error while performing gradle jmeter integration

Tags: gradle, jmeter

For Jmeter-Gradle integration I have created below build.gradle file and stored it on my local directory.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jmeter'

group = 'com.github.kulya'
archivesBaseName = 'jmeter-gradle-plugin'
ext.jmeterVersion = "2.13"
version = "1.3.3-$jmeterVersion-SNAPSHOT"

sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6


def bootClasspathStr = "${System.env.'JAVA_HOME'}/jre/lib/rt.jar"
project.tasks.withType(AbstractCompile, { AbstractCompile ac ->
    ac.options.bootClasspath = bootClasspathStr // options is always there but not defined on AbstractCompile so going to hit it anyway
})


repositories {
    maven {
          url "http://nexus2.sdmc.ao-srv.com/content/groups/inhouse_dit/"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "http://nexus2.sdmc.ao-srv.com/content/groups/inhouse_dit/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.1-2.6"
       //classpath 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.7.5'
    classpath ('com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13') {
            exclude group: 'xml-apis'
        }

    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

configurations {
    //workaround for jmeter defect 57555 (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57555)
    if (jmeterVersion == '2.12'){
        compile.exclude group: 'excalibur-fortress', module: 'excalibur-fortress-container-api'
        compile.exclude group: 'excalibur-fortress', module: 'excalibur-fortress-meta'

    }
    //workaround for jmeter defect 57748 (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57748)
    if (jmeterVersion == '2.13'){
        compile.exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
        compile.exclude group: 'commons-pool2', module: 'commons-pool2'
    }
}



dependencies {

    //common to all supported versions
    compile gradleApi(),
        localGroovy(),
        "org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4",
        "org.beanshell:bsh-core:2.0b4",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_http:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_junit:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_java:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jdbc:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_tcp:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mail:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ldap:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ftp:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_functions:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_monitors:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jms:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_config:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_junit:${jmeterVersion}"


    //version specific dependencies
    if (jmeterVersion > '2.7') {
        compile "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_native:${jmeterVersion}"
    }
    if (jmeterVersion > '2.9'){
        compile "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mongodb:${jmeterVersion}"
    }
    if (jmeterVersion < '2.13'){
        compile "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_report:${jmeterVersion}"
    }
    if (jmeterVersion > '2.9'){
        compile "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_config:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_junit-test:${jmeterVersion}",
        "org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mongodb:${jmeterVersion}"
    }
    if (jmeterVersion == '2.13'){
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.4.1",
            "org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.3"
    } 
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from 'build/docs/javadoc'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    classifier = 'sources'
}

jmeterRun.configure {
    jmeterTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/performanceTestDITAllTests.jmx"), file("src/test/jmeter/performanceTestDIT.jmx"), file

("src/test/jmeter/functionalTestDIT.jmx")]
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

processResources.doLast {
    ant.replace(
            file: "${project.buildDir}/resources/main/jmeter-plugin.properties",
            token: "@jmeter.version@",
            value: "$jmeterVersion"
    )
}
```

When used the command $ gradle clean, getting below error. Not able to resolve this. Could you please help me to resolve this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'JmeterGradle'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve jcharts:jcharts:0.7.5.
     Required by:
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mail:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_monitors:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jdbc:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ldap:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_config:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_functions:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ftp:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_http:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_tcp:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jms:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_junit:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_java:2.13
         :JmeterGradle:unspecified > com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13 > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mail:2.13 > org.
apache.jmeter:jorphan:2.13
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: jchart:jchart:0.7.5 Errors: bad group: expected='jcharts' found='jchart'
        bad module name: expected='jcharts' found='jchart'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 51.637 secs
```

Thanks for your help on this

Comment: Its not helpful for me. Still struggling to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a wrong pom in your repository that uses jchart instead of jcharts.

See:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-ignore-bad-pom-inconsistent-module-descriptor-and-download-jar/6495

Answer (score 0):

@UBIK LOAD PACK You are pointing out correct, they might have wrong pom.

I have also same issue, and got resolve by adding **jcenter()** and **mavenCentral()** in repositories block in **build.gradle** file and it is working.